# Get every days from given month of particular Year

Tags: ios, swift, date, calendar

Is it possible to get an array of Date for each day of a given Month and Year from Calendar components (Swift 3)

Currently I just find a way to get a count of days but nothing more.

The purpose is to develop my custom calendar but I get stuck to this phase...

The extension I'm trying to write will look like this:

```
extension Date 
{
    func getAllDays() -> [Date]
}
```

Or a method like that:

```
func getAllDays(month: Int, year: Int) -> [Date]
```

Answer (score 16):

Finally I find a way to do it:

```
extension Date
{    
    mutating func addDays(n: Int)
    {
        let cal = Calendar.current
        self = cal.date(byAdding: .day, value: n, to: self)!
    }

    func firstDayOfTheMonth() -> Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(from:
            Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year,.month], from: self))!
    }

    func getAllDays() -> [Date]
    {
        var days = [Date]()

        let calendar = Calendar.current

        let range = calendar.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: self)!

        var day = firstDayOfTheMonth()

        for _ in 1...range.count
        {
            days.append(day)
            day.addDays(n: 1)
        }

        return days
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
let allDays = Date().getAllDays()
```

output:

> 2017-06-01 22:00:00 +0000
>
> 2017-06-02 22:00:00 +0000
>
> 2017-06-03 22:00:00 +0000
>
> 2017-06-04 22:00:00 +0000
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> 2017-06-30 22:00:00 +0000

Answer (score 1):

Here a little bit better code for doing the same

```
extension Date {

    var startOfMonth: Date {
            return Calendar.iso8601.date(from: Calendar.iso8601.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: self))!
        }

    var daysOfMonth: [Date] {
        let startOfMonth = self.startOfMonth
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let range = calendar.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: self)!
        return range.compactMap{ calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: $0, to: startOfMonth)}
    }
}


extension Calendar {
    static let iso8601 = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
}
```

Comment: this will start from the second day of the month because range values starts from 1, so you are adding one day `value: $0` to the first day of the month

Comment: it will also give you the first day of the next month.